# how to subset time period from 1.1.1961 to 31.12.2010 in R

Tags: r, loops, time, period

I need a help with subseting a time period from 1.1.1961 to 31.12.2010. My data are txt files (names are for example 5020.txt, 4050.txt,8070.txt...). Each txt file consists of day, month, year and Qmax

```
day           month         year          Qmax          Comment
4             11            1929          50.3         -999 
22            4             1931          74           -999 
16            10            1932          93.5         -999 
30            10            1933          14.4         -999 
15            10            1934          48.3         -999 
13            4             1935          43.3         -999 
2             6             1936          40.8         -999 
15            3             1937          86.2         -999 
23            8             1938          90.7         -999 
15            5             1939          47.9         -999 
19            10            1941          82.2         -999 
9             4             1942          41.7         -999 
9             6             1943          60.5         -999 
9             12            1944          51.5         -999 
9             2             1946          26.7         -999 
7             4             1947          22.1         -999 
7             4             1948          61.2         -999 
20            6             1949          35           -999 
26            4             1950          21.4         -999 
20            3             1951          66           -999 
22            11            1952          46.9         -999 
2             7             1954          42.8         -999 
28            3             1955          41.5         -999 
19            4             1956          27.8         -999 
18            3             1957          32.6         -999 
29            6             1958          39           -999 
2             5             1959          35           -999 
26            7             1960          74.7         -999 
21            10            1961          17.6         -999 
6             3             1962          28.3         -999 
5             10            1963          19.9         -999 
12            10            1964          15.9         -999 
11            7             1965          23.2         -999 
3             12            1966          52.7         -999 
24            12            1967          23.2         -999 
13            4             1969          18.4         -999 
19            7             1970          40.5         -999 
18            5             1972          20           -999 
3             5             1973          10.8         -999
```

My code is following:

```
library(zoo)
setwd("H:/CLUSTERING/2cluster")

file_names = list.files("./data/")

AnnualMaxima <- vector("list", length(file_names))
names(AnnualMaxima) <- substr(file_names,1,nchar(file_names)-4)


for (i in 1:length(file_names)){

data_i = read.table(paste("./data/",file_names[i], sep=""), header = TRUE)
date_i <- as.Date(paste(data_i[,1],data_i[,2],data_i[,3]), format = "%d %m 
 %Y")
 flood_peaks_i <- zoo(data_i[,4],date_i)

 AnnualMaxima[[i]] <- flood_peaks_i

 }
```

My question is how to add to my loop that I want only time period from 1.1.1961 to 31.12.2010 ?
any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe consider adding what language are you coding in, so people can help you faster

Comment: I need it in R language

Comment: It doesnt work,

Comment: If `z` is a zoo object with Date class time index then this subsets it to the indicated dates: `z0 <- subset(z, time(z) >= "1960-01-01" & time(z) <= "2010-12-31")` .  An alternative is `z0 <- subset(z, format(time(z), "%Y") %in% 1960:2010)`

Comment: thanks, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dat$date_i <- with(dat, as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep="-")))
str( ind <- as.Date("1961-01-01") <= dat$date_i & dat$date_i <= as.Date("2010-12-31") )
#  logi [1:39] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
dat <- dat[ind,]
dat
#    day month year Qmax Comment     date_i
# 29  21    10 1961 17.6    -999 1961-10-21
# 30   6     3 1962 28.3    -999 1962-03-06
# 31   5    10 1963 19.9    -999 1963-10-05
# 32  12    10 1964 15.9    -999 1964-10-12
# 33  11     7 1965 23.2    -999 1965-07-11
# 34   3    12 1966 52.7    -999 1966-12-03
# 35  24    12 1967 23.2    -999 1967-12-24
# 36  13     4 1969 18.4    -999 1969-04-13
# 37  19     7 1970 40.5    -999 1970-07-19
# 38  18     5 1972 20.0    -999 1972-05-18
# 39   3     5 1973 10.8    -999 1973-05-03
```

And then, as necessary, `zoo`-ify:

```
zdat <- zoo::zoo(dat$Qmax, dat$date_i)
```

---

Input data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
day           month         year          Qmax          Comment
4             11            1929          50.3         -999 
22            4             1931          74           -999 
16            10            1932          93.5         -999 
30            10            1933          14.4         -999 
15            10            1934          48.3         -999 
13            4             1935          43.3         -999 
2             6             1936          40.8         -999 
15            3             1937          86.2         -999 
23            8             1938          90.7         -999 
15            5             1939          47.9         -999 
19            10            1941          82.2         -999 
9             4             1942          41.7         -999 
9             6             1943          60.5         -999 
9             12            1944          51.5         -999 
9             2             1946          26.7         -999 
7             4             1947          22.1         -999 
7             4             1948          61.2         -999 
20            6             1949          35           -999 
26            4             1950          21.4         -999 
20            3             1951          66           -999 
22            11            1952          46.9         -999 
2             7             1954          42.8         -999 
28            3             1955          41.5         -999 
19            4             1956          27.8         -999 
18            3             1957          32.6         -999 
29            6             1958          39           -999 
2             5             1959          35           -999 
26            7             1960          74.7         -999 
21            10            1961          17.6         -999 
6             3             1962          28.3         -999 
5             10            1963          19.9         -999 
12            10            1964          15.9         -999 
11            7             1965          23.2         -999 
3             12            1966          52.7         -999 
24            12            1967          23.2         -999 
13            4             1969          18.4         -999 
19            7             1970          40.5         -999 
18            5             1972          20           -999 
3             5             1973          10.8         -999')
```